# Chrome 110 Webdriver 110: Cannot start session : DevTools client failed to connect:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome Version: Version 110.0.5481.177 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Chrome Driver Version: 110.0.5481.77
Java Version 17
Selenium version:4.8.1
macOS 13.2.1

```
After updating to Chrome 110 and downloading the relevant support driver I can no longer start a session. The error being produced is:
    Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 6304
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1677671505.261][WARNING]: Browser-wide DevTools client failed to connect: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.177) 
Host info: host: 'Adam.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:6c:2c11:1a77:e83c%en0'
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.2.1', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Driver setup code:

```
System.out.println("LOOKING FOR DRIVER");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./chromedriver");
System.out.println("DRIVER FOUND");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("user-agent=GetMyBoat/Test");
setupDriver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

I have also tried with out the  headless argument

Most of the information online points to mismatch in version between the driver and chrome, however this is not the case here as I have the same version running

I have tried running it with headless mode

Completely uninstalling Chrome and relevant data then reinstalling

This only started happening once i updated to Chrome 110

Answer (score 0):

On the latest version of Selenium introduced selenium manager where you no longer need to define chrome driver path on your code

```
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Just simply call chromedriver is enough to open browser.

Reference# https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/

Answer (score 0):

This solution from Titus Fortner worked for me. The selenium manager didn't.

> "If people are using Java 11+ can you try using the new http client
> and see if that fixes the issue without needing to update the options?
>
> https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/using-java11-httpclient/ "